# Cloth simulation ready before frame 0

Tags: modeling, unity, cloth-simulation

I'd like to know if there is a way to "pre-calculate" a cloth. I explain:
I'm modeling a character for a game, and I want to export the animation to Unity3D. The problem is that the cloth simulator takes 1 or 2 frames to put clothes well.
And having a big plane in an animation of the game is not cool.
So if someone knows if it is possible or to "cut" the exported anim in unity or to pre-render it before frame 0...
Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvJU3.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Cloth Cache settings and put a negative value into the start field. So animation will begin before timeline starts. Then press "Bake".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing, for a flag in my animation.
My solve for now is to start my animation scene at frame 150, when the flag has settled down, instead of 0. Then I adjusted my end time to account for the offset.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually specify the cloth cache frame to start before zero. I start mine at -66. That way when you bake, the flag is fully settled down by frame 1.